# JavaScript patterns and garbage collection

Tags: javascript, memory-management, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I've been using two versions of a JavaScript pattern for a while that I picked up from Addy Osmani called the module pattern. [view it here](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#modulepatternjavascript)

The first version of this pattern uses an object literal:

```
var x = {
  b: function() {
    return 'text';
  },
  c: function() {
    var h = this.b();
    h += ' for reading';
  }
}
alert(x.b()) // alerts text.
```

while the other version uses a self executing function:

```
var y = (function() {
     var first = 'some value';
     var second = 'some other value';
     function concat() {
       return first += ' '+second;
     }

     return {
       setNewValue: function(userValue) {
         first = userValue;
       },
       showNewVal: function() {
         alert(concat());
       }
     }
})();

y.setNewValue('something else');
y.showNewVal();
```

Given the examples above, are either of these two patterns (not taking into account any event listeners) garbage collection friendly (given the way they reference themselves)?

Comment: I think so. Whenever you don't have anything pointing to those objects, they'll become eligible for gc (including the closure).

Comment: @bfavaretto the first one will (when i use it) usually reference it self a lot like "this.c() or this.b()" can self reference keep the main object from being GC'd?

Comment: I'm no expert, but again I don't think so (especially because `this` is determined on call-time in js).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  There's no difference as far as what becomes unreachable when.

Both use a global variable that pins the API in place, so will not be collectible until the frame is unloaded and dropped from history.

The second allocates and holds onto an extra activation frame (for module-locals `first` and `second`), but that's a pretty minor cost.

Comment: so technically speaking if i were to use the "delete" keyword on either one "var x or var y" like so "delete x or delete y" would that essentially make it garbage collectible?

Comment: @zero, no.  `delete window.x` would.  `delete x` is a no-op or error in strict mode I think.